# how do I pass lists as arguments in R?

Tags: r

I have a function `fetchWeather(city,month1,year1,...)` that takes an unlimited combination of month/year inputs and spits out weather data for those periods.

I'd like to make it a little more compact by doing some combinations by shorthand. so for example, rather than

```
fetchWeather(Boston,4,2015,5,2015,6,2015,7,2015,8,2015,9,2015,10,2015)
```

I'd like to do

```
jv15<- c(4,2015,5,2015,6,2015,7,2015,8,2015,9,2015,10,2015)
```

and then call

```
fetchWeather(Boston,jv15)
```

but I can't get this to work.

I'm pretty new to R and I imagine that this is a pretty easy solve but I can't seem to figure it out. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Change the function definition to `fetchWeather(city, dates)`, and then parse the `dates` vector inside the function to get the individual months and years.

Comment: For someone new to R, it's pretty impressive if you even know how to write a function that takes unlimited args like that. However, I think it would be a lot cleaner if the function was simply vectorized to take args like the cols of `data.frame(city = "Boston", month = 4:10, year = 2015L)`. Anyway, your immediate problem can probably be addressed with `do.call`.

Comment: ytk, will that work even in a yy-mm format? i.e is that stored as a string, or as date/time (is how it would make sense in a different language, at least). ...nevermind I understand now

Answer (score 6):

Your error might be that boston is not in quotes, but assuming that Boston is truly a variable...

You can use 'do.call'

Takes a function and a list and calls a function with that list as arguments.

So first you'd want to prepend Boston onto your list and then do.call.

```
out.weather <- do.call(fetchWeather, c(Boston,jv15))
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would prefer this type of function to be defined in such a way that there is only *one* argument that is repeated in the ellipsis (instead of two).

So instead of working with `year` and `month`, I would rather define this function with a `date` argument. In that case, you can convert the `...` to a list internally, and you can define the function in such a way that `date` can either be a single date or a list of dates.

See the example below.

```
date <- c(2003,6)
date.list <- list(c(2001,4),c(2002,5))

fetchWeather <- function(city, date, ...){

  .date <- list(...)
  if(!is.list(date)) date <- list(date)

  date <- c(date,.date)

  out <- sapply(date,.internal.fetchWeather)
  return(out)

}
.internal.fetchWeather <- identity

fetchWeather("Boston", date.list, date, date+1, date+2)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,] 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005
# [2,]    4    5    6    7    8
```

Note that, because you did not provide any code in your question, I do not know what your function will do.

Therefore, I used a function named `.internal.fetchWeather` as a placeholder for what you want to do for each date. In my example, I simply used the identity function, which prints the years and months to the console.